# OpenCL on Xcode error: global variables must have a constant address space qualifier const char *KernelSource = \n"\

Tags: opencl

I tried to compile this code in Xcode, but I get the above error

```
const char *KernelSource =   "\n"\
"__kernel void pi(           \n"\
"__global float* out, \n"\
"uint cntSteps        \n"\
")                                                          \n"\
"{                                                          \n"\
" const uint idThread = get_local_id(0);                  \n"\
" uint numprocs = get_global_size(0);                     \n"\
" const float local_num = (float)cntSteps / numprocs;     \n"\
"float step = 1.0 / cntSteps;                            \n"\
"float sum = 0.0;                                        \n"\
"float x;                                                \n"\
"int localmax = (idThread + 1) * local_num;              \n"\
"for(uint i = idThread * local_num; i < localmax; i++)   \n"\
"{                                                          \n"\
"x = step * (i + 0.5);                                \n"\
"sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);                     \n"\
"}                                                       \n"\
"out[idThread] = sum * step;                             \n"\
"}                                                          \n";
```

Any idea what is wrong with this kernel !,

Comment: From the error message, it seems like the string assignment is not being parsed right. The error message is missing the quote before the first backslash. Is that a typo or really what Xcode output? If the latter, inspect that first quote. It's not a "smart quote" by accident or something, is it? Try replacing everything with a single-line kernel with no line break ("\n" or line continuation backslashes) and see if that works, then add things back until it breaks (then you'll know what breaks it).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I resolved the issue by Creating the new kenel file e.g calc_pi.cl without any those new lines and backslashes and include it in Xcode project by 
#include "calc_pi.cl.h" in main.cpp file. 
It sounds that, the header should be generated at compile time in Xcode. The first mistake I did was I included it as calc_pi.cl instead of cal_pi.cl.h

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

1. create a kernel file e.g calc_pi.cl

// calc_pi.cl

```
kernel void pi(global float* out, uint cntSteps) {
   const uint idThread = get_local_id(0);
   uint numprocs = get_global_size(0);
   const float local_num = (float)cntSteps / numprocs;
   float step = 1.0 / cntSteps;
   float sum = 0.0;
   float x;
   int localmax = (idThread + 1) * local_num;
   for(uint i = idThread * local_num; i < localmax; i++) {
      x = step * (i + 0.5);
      sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
   }
   out[idThread] = sum * step;
}

2. in main.cpp 
// include all necessary headers and the above kernel e.g 
#include "calc_pi.cl.h"
//.. more includes
```

1. then work with your kernel

**I hope this helps someone starting to work with OpenCL in Xcode.**